# Why is this Repository Method not working?

Tags: typo3-flow

I used this Repository Method in an Extbase Project and it worked fine.

```
public function findRandom() {
    $rows = $this->createQuery()->execute()->count();
    $row_number = mt_rand(0, max(0, ($rows - 1)));
    return $this->createQuery()->setOffset($row_number)->setLimit(1)->execute();
}
```

It is not working in TYPO3 Flow. Why? And what should I change?

Comment: "not working" meaning what exactly? Do you get an error message or a MySQL error?

Comment: $row_number gets a random integer value.

The second query doesnt return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not mention, the queryResult is not the object it self. Its an array. My code above is working.

This is a difference between extbase and flow3. Flow3 returns an array. Extbase the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Sound strange Flow must return an object in this, like Extbase does, or in your case an QueryResultInterface of one object, if you need directly an object, you can use this kind of code:

```
$query->execute()->getFirst();
```

Hope that help,

Comment: This did the trick for me! Change line »return $this->createQuery()->setOffset($row_number)->setLimit(1)->execute();« to »return $this->createQuery()->setOffset($row_number)->setLimit(1)->execute()->getFirst;« to return the desired object in TYPO3 Flow.